# How to check if category doesn't exist?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony1, symfony-1.2

I have a blog post URL as follow:

> /blog/testing-url

which was linked to a category & that category has been deleted! What i want now is to show the post. The category of this post has been deleted but how can i check if the category doesn't exists? I tried the following

**if(isset($category))** but this isn't working.

Error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getCategory() on a non-object
>   in /httpdocs/apps/mainv2/modules/blog/actions/actions.class.php on
>   line 168

This is a piece of code where the error is happening:

```
  public function executeEdit(sfWebRequest $request) { #edit video
    ...

    $this->nrpag = $request->getParameter('nrpag', 1);
    $cats = array(); #video_cat
    $c = new Criteria();
    $c->addAscendingOrderByColumn(VideoCatPeer::CATEGORY);
    $vcats = VideoCatPeer::doSelect($c);
    foreach ($vcats as $vcat) {
        if($vcat != NULL){
            $cats[$vcat->getId()] = $vcat->getCategory();
        }else{
            continue;
        }
    }
    $this->cats = $cats;

    ...
  }
```

Comment: *"if(isset($category)) but this isn't working."* - I don't see where `$category` is defined.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner code added

Comment: Yeah, the code snippet you supplied does not show the $category variable, nor does it show the getCategory method being called.  Are you sure you pulled the code from actions.class.php?

Comment: @R.Smith please check the update

Comment: @ReynierPM Please read the error it says it is on line 168 so there code hasn't getCategory func however i added now in edit :)

Comment: What is `Category` a related entity? Pls remove what's not needed from there and leave only what's useful :) I am seeing a lot of stuff there unrelated even what you said about line `168` does not make any sense. I am assuming your problem is at `$cats[$vcat->getId()] = $vcat->getCategory();` am I right?

Comment: @ReynierPM yes the category ID gets inserted in the blog table.

Comment: @ReynierPM that's what i am saying that the error shows that there is problem at line 168 but the getCategory func is below that line

Comment: I have clean out your OP (pls check if I leave only the relevant part - the one that help us), now what is `Category` an Entity? A column in the DB? A relationship between entities?

Comment: Yes it is an Entity! @ReynierPM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether the object `$vcat` has an instance of the `Category` entity and do something in such case. Ex:

```
foreach ($vcats as $vcat) {
    if($vcat != NULL && $vcat->getCategory() instanceof Category){
        $cats[$vcat->getId()] = $vcat->getCategory();
    } 
}
```

I haven't tried is just a though. Let me know if that worked